# Regex validation in javascript with setCustomValidity

Tags: javascript

```js
var ck_login = new RegExp("/^[a-zA-Z]{5,12}$/");
var ck_password = new RegExp("/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z]).{6,16}$/");

function validate(){
var login = document.getElementById("login").value;
var loginErr = document.getElementById("login");


var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
var passwordErr = document.getElementById("password");

 if (ck_password.test(password) == false) {
  passwordErr.setCustomValidity('Password must have at least 6 characters at least no more than 16. At least one low and one number');
  return false;
 }
 if (ck_login.test(login) == false) {
  loginErr.setCustomValidity('Login must have at least 5 characters and no more than 12');
  return false;
 }
 return true;

}
```

```html
<form action="" method="post" onSubmit="return validate();">
  <label>Username:</label>
  <input type="text" name="login" id="login" required="required">
  <label>Password:</label>
  <input type="text" name="password" id="password" required="required">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

I am trying to do form validations where Login must have at least 5 characters and no more than 12 and Password must have at least 6 characters at least no more than 16. At least one low and one number.

**Regex is correct but it's not working in javascript properly. I can't find what mistake I am doing.**

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do not create regular expressions using the RegExp constructor.

Do it like this:

```
var ck_login = /^[a-zA-Z]{5,12}$/;
var ck_password = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z]).{6,16}$/;
```

If you are going to use the RegExp constructor, don't use slashes at the beginning-end of the string.

```
var ck_login = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z]{5,12}$");
var ck_password = new RegExp("^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z]).{6,16}$");
```

Comment: Ok some Improvement now its showing but another problem is that password is wrong then it shows error. If I fix password and  put wrong login and click submit it still shows password error at password box. Can make a snippet of working code please. Thanks

Comment: This is from MDN: "The HTMLSelectElement.setCustomValidity() method sets the custom validity message for the selection element to the specified message. Use the empty string to indicate that the element does not have a custom validity error."

Comment: Just call `loginErr.setCustomValidity("");` and `passwordErr.setCustomValidity("");` right before the `return true;` statement.

Comment: Still Same problem.